# Convex Functions are twice differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

I am trying to prove that a convex function is $\varphi:R\to R$ is twice  differentiable a.e. I am aware this is a special case of the Busemann-Feller theorem . But I find the proof quite dense, and difficult. For the real case, the proof is easier but I am having difficulty. I have proved that $\varphi'$ is right diffble everywhere and $\varphi'(x+)$ is increasing (that is increasing for all x not just a.e. x)
. Now I cannot use the fact that $\varphi'$ is monotone and is thus diffble a.e since everything I have is for $\varphi'(x+)$ not $\varphi'(x)$. I need to show that $\varphi''(x+)$ exists a.e. and then finally $\varphi''(x)=\varphi''(x+)$ whenever $\varphi''(x)$ exists. However I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: What about the absolute value function?

Comment: The absolute value function is absolutely fine. It is everywhere twice differentiable up to the origin and the origin has measure zero.

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to note that the monotone functions $\varphi'_-$ and $\varphi'_r$ coincide a.e. (even outside of a countable set) and apply the Lebesgue differentiation theorem to both to obtain that $\varphi'$ is a.e. differentiable ?

Comment: what is $\varphi_r'$? if you mean $\varphi_+'$. then yes I have that $\varphi_+'=\varphi_-'$ outside of a countable set. The Lebesgue differentiation theorem concerns averaging functions approximating a specific value that a function attains?

Comment: I'm referencing the theorem of Lebesgue asserting that monotone functions are a.e. differentiable. Also, yes, I meant $\varphi'_-$.

Comment: Yeah okay, that is actually my precise problem!, I dont have that $\varphi'$ is monotone (of course it only is defined a.e.) I do have that $\varphi_+'$ is monotone and so I can deduce that $\varphi''_+$ exists a.e. The problem is that, I cannot use that "a.e monotone functions are a.e. diffble"

Comment: There is a relatively nice proof of this in the appendix to this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9207212.pdf  (Also, $\varphi'$ is non-decreasing if and only if $\varphi$ is convex --- this applies to both right- and left-hand derivatives.)